# React Component is rendering twice

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have no idea why, the first render shows an empty object and the second shows my data:

```js
function RecipeList(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(props.recipes)}
            {/*{props.recipes.hits.map(r => (*/}
            {/*    <Recipe initial="lb" title={r.recipe.label} date={'1 Hour Ago'}/>*/}
        </div>
    )
}

const RECIPES_URL = 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://test-es.edamam.com/search?i?app_id=426&q=chicken&to=10'
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(RECIPES_URL)
            .then(res => {
                setData(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, []);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <NavBar/>
      <RecipeList recipes={data}/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't know why and I have struggled here for over an hour (React newbie), so I must be missing something.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct behavior. You have an asynchronous request which when completes updates the state. This causes a rerender. The state is passed down as props to RecipeList, but it's initial state is an empty object, so will only include the data on the second render.

Comment: A good approach to dealing with this is rendering a 'Loading..' component whilst the data is being fetched / undifined, and then rendering RecipeList when it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The reason you see two console logs is because, the first time `RecipeList` is called with no data (empty object), and the second time when the data becomes available. If you would like to render it only when the data is available you could do something like `{Object.keys(data).length > 0 && <RecipeList recipes={data}/>}`. By the way this is called conditional rendering.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal, React will render your component first with no data. Then when your `axios.get` returns and update data, it will be rendered again with the new data

Comment: Is this so users see all the static data in the meanwhile until the dynamic data has been fetched?

Comment: It's just that your `axios`.get is asynchronous, so you will receive an answer in the future. And while you're waiting for axios to get back to you, then React is still doing its job: render your UI. Then later when data is updated, React knows that your UI depends on it, so it will render a second time